# How can I align a heading element to center of a section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to align the h1 element with class `wish` to the center of its section, both Horizontally and vertically. But am not able to do it for some reason. Please help me out.

Below is the HTML, CSS and JS code.

Note: Since the code was too long it is only the concerned part of the HTML code. I'll put the complete code if you require it.

The Complete CSS Code is given because I thought it might be necessary for you to understand things better.

```js
/* =================== WISH ================*/
// helper functions
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2
const random = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min | 0
const timestamp = _ => new Date().getTime()

// container
class Birthday {
  constructor() {
    this.resize()

    // create a lovely place to store the firework
    this.fireworks = []
    this.counter = 0

  }

  resize() {
    this.width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    let center = this.width / 2 | 0
    this.spawnA = center - center / 4 | 0
    this.spawnB = center + center / 4 | 0

    this.height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight
    this.spawnC = this.height * .1
    this.spawnD = this.height * .5

  }

  onClick(evt) {
    let x = evt.clientX || evt.touches && evt.touches[0].pageX
    let y = evt.clientY || evt.touches && evt.touches[0].pageY

    let count = random(3, 5)
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) this.fireworks.push(new Firework(
      random(this.spawnA, this.spawnB),
      this.height,
      x,
      y,
      random(0, 260),
      random(30, 110)))

    this.counter = -1

  }

  update(delta) {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'hard-light'
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(20,20,20,${ 7 * delta })`
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter'
    for (let firework of this.fireworks) firework.update(delta)

    // if enough time passed... create new new firework
    this.counter += delta * 3 // each second
    if (this.counter >= 1) {
      this.fireworks.push(new Firework(
        random(this.spawnA, this.spawnB),
        this.height,
        random(0, this.width),
        random(this.spawnC, this.spawnD),
        random(0, 360),
        random(30, 110)))
      this.counter = 0
    }

    // remove the dead fireworks
    if (this.fireworks.length > 1000) this.fireworks = this.fireworks.filter(firework => !firework.dead)

  }
}

class Firework {
  constructor(x, y, targetX, targetY, shade, offsprings) {
    this.dead = false
    this.offsprings = offsprings

    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.targetX = targetX
    this.targetY = targetY

    this.shade = shade
    this.history = []
  }
  update(delta) {
    if (this.dead) return

    let xDiff = this.targetX - this.x
    let yDiff = this.targetY - this.y
    if (Math.abs(xDiff) > 3 || Math.abs(yDiff) > 3) { // is still moving
      this.x += xDiff * 2 * delta
      this.y += yDiff * 2 * delta

      this.history.push({
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y
      })

      if (this.history.length > 20) this.history.shift()

    } else {
      if (this.offsprings && !this.madeChilds) {

        let babies = this.offsprings / 2
        for (let i = 0; i < babies; i++) {
          let targetX = this.x + this.offsprings * Math.cos(PI2 * i / babies) | 0
          let targetY = this.y + this.offsprings * Math.sin(PI2 * i / babies) | 0

          birthday.fireworks.push(new Firework(this.x, this.y, targetX, targetY, this.shade, 0))

        }

      }
      this.madeChilds = true
      this.history.shift()
    }

    if (this.history.length === 0) this.dead = true
    else if (this.offsprings) {
      for (let i = 0; this.history.length > i; i++) {
        let point = this.history[i]
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + this.shade + ',100%,' + i + '%)'
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 1, 0, PI2, false)
        ctx.fill()
      }
    } else {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + this.shade + ',100%,50%)'
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 1, 0, PI2, false)
      ctx.fill()
    }

  }
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('birthday')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let then = timestamp()

let birthday = new Birthday
window.onresize = () => birthday.resize()
document.onclick = evt => birthday.onClick(evt)
document.ontouchstart = evt => birthday.onClick(evt)

;
(function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)

  let now = timestamp()
  let delta = now - then

  then = now
  birthday.update(delta / 1000)


})()
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");

/*===== VARIABLES CSS =====*/

:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --font-semi: 600;
  /*===== Colors =====*/
  /*Purple 260 - Red 355 - Blue 224 - Pink 340*/
  /* HSL color mode */
  --hue-color: 224;
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 89%, 60%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 80%, 43%);
  --second-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 56%, 12%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 56%, 12%);
  --container-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 0%, 100%);
  ;
  /*===== Fuente y tipografia =====*/
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --big-font-size: 2rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  --medium-font-size: .875rem;
  --small-font-size: .813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: .75rem;
  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  /*===== Margins =====*/
  --mb-0-25: .25rem;
  --mb-2: 1rem;
  --mb-4: 2rem;
  --mb-5: 2.5rem;
  --mb-6: 3rem;
  /*===== z index =====*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-back: -10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
   :root {
    --big-font-size: 3.5rem;
    --h2-font-size: 2rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .875rem;
  }
}


/*===== BASE =====*/

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
}

body {
  margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  color: var(--text-color);
  background-color: var(--container-color);
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}


/*===== CLASS CSS ===== */

.section-title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-top: var(--mb-2);
  text-align: center;
}

.section-title::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 64px;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.section {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 0 4rem;
}


/*===== LAYOUT =====*/

.bd-grid {
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: grid;
  margin-left: var(--mb-2);
  margin-right: var(--mb-2);
}

.l-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(146, 161, 176, 0.15);
}


/*========== Variables Dark theme ==========*/

body.dark-theme {
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 89%, 60%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 80%, 43%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 89%, 100%);
  --second-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 80%, 40%);
  --container-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 86%, 12%);
}


/*========== Button Dark/Light ==========*/

.change-theme {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1.8rem;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*===== NAV =====*/

.nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: var(--header-height);
    right: -100%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: var(--second-color);
    transition: .5s;
  }
}

.nav__item {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.nav__link {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  position: relative;
}

.nav__link:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.nav__toggle {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Active menu*/

.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}


/*=== Show menu ===*/

.show {
  right: 0;
}


/*===== HOME =====*/

.home {
  position: relative;
  row-gap: 5rem;
  padding: 4rem 0 5rem;
}

.home__data {
  align-self: center;
}

.home__title {
  font-size: var(--big-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-5);
}

.home__title-color {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.home__social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.home__social-icon {
  width: max-content;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.home__social-icon:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.home__img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 260px;
}

.home__blob {
  margin-bottom: 14%;
  fill: var(--first-color);
}

.home__blob-img {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  width: 360px;
}


/*BUTTONS*/

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  color: #fff;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  transition: .3s;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}


/* ===== ABOUT =====*/

.about__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.about__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
}

.about__img {
  justify-self: center;
}

.about__img img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}


/* ===== SKILLS =====*/

.skills__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
}

.skills__text {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 25px rgba(14, 36, 49, 0.15);
}

.skills__icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: var(--mb-2);
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__names {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.skills__bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  height: .25rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  z-index: var(--z-back);
}

.qualities__trust {
  width: 100%;
}

.qualities__loyalty {
  width: 100%;
}

.qualities__respect {
  width: 90%;
}

.qualities__understanding {
  width: 90%;
}

.skills__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
}


/* ===== WORK =====*/

.work__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
}

.work__img {
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 25px rgba(14, 36, 49, 0.15);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.work__img img {
  transition: 1s;
}

.work__img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}


/* ===== CONTACT =====*/

.contact__input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  border: 1.5px solid var(--second-color);
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.contact__button {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* WISH */

canvas {
  display: block
}

.wish {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 22%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 900;
}


/* ===== FOOTER =====*/

.footer {
  background-color: var(--second-color);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.footer__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.footer__social {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.footer__icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 var(--mb-2);
}

.footer__copy {
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
}


/* ===== SCROLL TOP ===== */

.scrolltop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: -20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .3rem;
  background: var(--first-color);
  border-radius: .4rem;
  z-index: var(--z-tooltip);
  transition: .4s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.scrolltop:hover {
  background-color: var(--first-color-alt);
}

.scrolltop__icon {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Show scrolltop */

.show-scroll {
  visibility: visible;
  bottom: 1.5rem;
}


/* ===== MEDIA QUERIES=====*/

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .home {
    row-gap: 2rem;
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .home {
    padding: 4rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .home__social {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  .home__social-icon {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: var(--mb-4);
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 300px;
    bottom: 25%;
  }
  .about__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    text-align: initial;
  }
  .skills__container {
    grid-template-columns: .7fr;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 1rem;
  }
  .work__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    column-gap: 2rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  .contact__form {
    width: 360px;
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  .contact__container {
    justify-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .section {
    padding-top: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
  }
  .section-title {
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-6);
  }
  .section-title::after {
    width: 80px;
    top: 3rem;
  }
  .nav {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1.5rem);
  }
  .nav__list {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .nav__item {
    margin-left: var(--mb-6);
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .nav__toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .change-theme {
    position: initial;
    margin-left: var(--mb-2);
  }
  .nav__link {
    color: var(--text-color);
  }
  .home {
    padding: 8rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 400px;
    bottom: 10%;
  }
  .about__container {
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  .about__img img {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .skills__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    column-gap: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: initial;
  }
  .work__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    column-gap: 2rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .bd-grid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .home {
    padding: 10rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 450px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--===== WISH =====-->
<section class="wish__section section" id="wish">
  <h1 class="wish">Happy Birthday!</h1>
  <canvas id="birthday">
            </canvas>
</section>
</main>

<!--===== SCROLL REVEAL =====-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>

<!--===== MAIN JS =====-->
<!-- script src="assets/js/main.js"></script -->
```

Comment: Any reason standard [CSS techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564/1264804) don't do the job? A quick test in the browser inspector seems to show that it would.

Comment: Uhh acually if you run the code you'll see the CSS and JS code are not just for the alignment. But yeah I get your point. I'll update the code

Comment: I did run the code, right after I built the demo for you. The script doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. Nor does 99% of the CSS.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please work to create a [mcve]—with an emphasis on minimal. As others have pointed out, you've included a lot of code that's irrelevant to your centering problem. It's generally considered discourteous to ask people to comb through irrelevant code instead of during the work yourself to remove the chaff.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to `.wish__section` with CSS so that the container centers the title for you.

I also removed the CSS located in `.wish` related to centering so that the styling didn't conflict.

If you need Happy Birthday to live on two separate lines, add a `<br>` tag in between Happy & Birthday for your title.

```js
/* =================== WISH ================*/
// helper functions
const PI2 = Math.PI * 2
const random = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min | 0
const timestamp = _ => new Date().getTime()

// container
class Birthday {
  constructor() {
    this.resize()

    // create a lovely place to store the firework
    this.fireworks = []
    this.counter = 0

  }

  resize() {
    this.width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    let center = this.width / 2 | 0
    this.spawnA = center - center / 4 | 0
    this.spawnB = center + center / 4 | 0

    this.height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight
    this.spawnC = this.height * .1
    this.spawnD = this.height * .5

  }

  onClick(evt) {
    let x = evt.clientX || evt.touches && evt.touches[0].pageX
    let y = evt.clientY || evt.touches && evt.touches[0].pageY

    let count = random(3, 5)
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) this.fireworks.push(new Firework(
      random(this.spawnA, this.spawnB),
      this.height,
      x,
      y,
      random(0, 260),
      random(30, 110)))

    this.counter = -1

  }

  update(delta) {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'hard-light'
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(20,20,20,${ 7 * delta })`
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter'
    for (let firework of this.fireworks) firework.update(delta)

    // if enough time passed... create new new firework
    this.counter += delta * 3 // each second
    if (this.counter >= 1) {
      this.fireworks.push(new Firework(
        random(this.spawnA, this.spawnB),
        this.height,
        random(0, this.width),
        random(this.spawnC, this.spawnD),
        random(0, 360),
        random(30, 110)))
      this.counter = 0
    }

    // remove the dead fireworks
    if (this.fireworks.length > 1000) this.fireworks = this.fireworks.filter(firework => !firework.dead)

  }
}

class Firework {
  constructor(x, y, targetX, targetY, shade, offsprings) {
    this.dead = false
    this.offsprings = offsprings

    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.targetX = targetX
    this.targetY = targetY

    this.shade = shade
    this.history = []
  }
  update(delta) {
    if (this.dead) return

    let xDiff = this.targetX - this.x
    let yDiff = this.targetY - this.y
    if (Math.abs(xDiff) > 3 || Math.abs(yDiff) > 3) { // is still moving
      this.x += xDiff * 2 * delta
      this.y += yDiff * 2 * delta

      this.history.push({
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y
      })

      if (this.history.length > 20) this.history.shift()

    } else {
      if (this.offsprings && !this.madeChilds) {

        let babies = this.offsprings / 2
        for (let i = 0; i < babies; i++) {
          let targetX = this.x + this.offsprings * Math.cos(PI2 * i / babies) | 0
          let targetY = this.y + this.offsprings * Math.sin(PI2 * i / babies) | 0

          birthday.fireworks.push(new Firework(this.x, this.y, targetX, targetY, this.shade, 0))

        }

      }
      this.madeChilds = true
      this.history.shift()
    }

    if (this.history.length === 0) this.dead = true
    else if (this.offsprings) {
      for (let i = 0; this.history.length > i; i++) {
        let point = this.history[i]
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + this.shade + ',100%,' + i + '%)'
        ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 1, 0, PI2, false)
        ctx.fill()
      }
    } else {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + this.shade + ',100%,50%)'
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 1, 0, PI2, false)
      ctx.fill()
    }

  }
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('birthday')
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let then = timestamp()

let birthday = new Birthday
window.onresize = () => birthday.resize()
document.onclick = evt => birthday.onClick(evt)
document.ontouchstart = evt => birthday.onClick(evt)

;
(function loop() {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)

  let now = timestamp()
  let delta = now - then

  then = now
  birthday.update(delta / 1000)


})()
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");

/*===== VARIABLES CSS =====*/

:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --font-semi: 600;
  /*===== Colors =====*/
  /*Purple 260 - Red 355 - Blue 224 - Pink 340*/
  /* HSL color mode */
  --hue-color: 224;
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 89%, 60%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 80%, 43%);
  --second-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 56%, 12%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 56%, 12%);
  --container-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 0%, 100%);
  ;
  /*===== Fuente y tipografia =====*/
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --big-font-size: 2rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  --medium-font-size: .875rem;
  --small-font-size: .813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: .75rem;
  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  /*===== Margins =====*/
  --mb-0-25: .25rem;
  --mb-2: 1rem;
  --mb-4: 2rem;
  --mb-5: 2.5rem;
  --mb-6: 3rem;
  /*===== z index =====*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-back: -10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
   :root {
    --big-font-size: 3.5rem;
    --h2-font-size: 2rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .875rem;
  }
}


/*===== BASE =====*/

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
}

body {
  margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  color: var(--text-color);
  background-color: var(--container-color);
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}


/*===== CLASS CSS ===== */

.section-title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-top: var(--mb-2);
  text-align: center;
}

.section-title::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 64px;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.section {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 0 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*===== LAYOUT =====*/

.bd-grid {
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: grid;
  margin-left: var(--mb-2);
  margin-right: var(--mb-2);
}

.l-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(146, 161, 176, 0.15);
}


/*========== Variables Dark theme ==========*/

body.dark-theme {
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 89%, 60%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 80%, 43%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 89%, 100%);
  --second-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 80%, 40%);
  --container-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 86%, 12%);
}


/*========== Button Dark/Light ==========*/

.change-theme {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 1.8rem;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*===== NAV =====*/

.nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: var(--header-height);
    right: -100%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: var(--second-color);
    transition: .5s;
  }
}

.nav__item {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.nav__link {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  position: relative;
}

.nav__link:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.nav__toggle {
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Active menu*/

.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}


/*=== Show menu ===*/

.show {
  right: 0;
}


/*===== HOME =====*/

.home {
  position: relative;
  row-gap: 5rem;
  padding: 4rem 0 5rem;
}

.home__data {
  align-self: center;
}

.home__title {
  font-size: var(--big-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-5);
}

.home__title-color {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.home__social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.home__social-icon {
  width: max-content;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.home__social-icon:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.home__img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 260px;
}

.home__blob {
  margin-bottom: 14%;
  fill: var(--first-color);
}

.home__blob-img {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  width: 360px;
}


/*BUTTONS*/

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  color: #fff;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  transition: .3s;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}


/* ===== ABOUT =====*/

.about__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.about__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
}

.about__img {
  justify-self: center;
}

.about__img img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}


/* ===== SKILLS =====*/

.skills__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
}

.skills__text {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 25px rgba(14, 36, 49, 0.15);
}

.skills__icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: var(--mb-2);
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__names {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.skills__bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  height: .25rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  z-index: var(--z-back);
}

.qualities__trust {
  width: 100%;
}

.qualities__loyalty {
  width: 100%;
}

.qualities__respect {
  width: 90%;
}

.qualities__understanding {
  width: 90%;
}

.skills__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
}


/* ===== WORK =====*/

.work__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
}

.work__img {
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 25px rgba(14, 36, 49, 0.15);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.work__img img {
  transition: 1s;
}

.work__img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}


/* ===== CONTACT =====*/

.contact__input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  border: 1.5px solid var(--second-color);
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.contact__button {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* WISH */

canvas {
  display: block
}

.wish {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ===== FOOTER =====*/

.footer {
  background-color: var(--second-color);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.footer__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.footer__social {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.footer__icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 var(--mb-2);
}

.footer__copy {
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
}


/* ===== SCROLL TOP ===== */

.scrolltop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: -20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .3rem;
  background: var(--first-color);
  border-radius: .4rem;
  z-index: var(--z-tooltip);
  transition: .4s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.scrolltop:hover {
  background-color: var(--first-color-alt);
}

.scrolltop__icon {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Show scrolltop */

.show-scroll {
  visibility: visible;
  bottom: 1.5rem;
}


/* ===== MEDIA QUERIES=====*/

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .home {
    row-gap: 2rem;
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 200px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .home {
    padding: 4rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .home__social {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  .home__social-icon {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: var(--mb-4);
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 300px;
    bottom: 25%;
  }
  .about__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    text-align: initial;
  }
  .skills__container {
    grid-template-columns: .7fr;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 1rem;
  }
  .work__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    column-gap: 2rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  .contact__form {
    width: 360px;
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  .contact__container {
    justify-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .section {
    padding-top: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
  }
  .section-title {
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-6);
  }
  .section-title::after {
    width: 80px;
    top: 3rem;
  }
  .nav {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1.5rem);
  }
  .nav__list {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .nav__item {
    margin-left: var(--mb-6);
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .nav__toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .change-theme {
    position: initial;
    margin-left: var(--mb-2);
  }
  .nav__link {
    color: var(--text-color);
  }
  .home {
    padding: 8rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 400px;
    bottom: 10%;
  }
  .about__container {
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }
  .about__img img {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .skills__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    column-gap: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: initial;
  }
  .work__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    column-gap: 2rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .bd-grid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .home {
    padding: 10rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 450px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--===== WISH =====-->
<section class="wish__section section" id="wish">
  <h1 class="wish">Happy Birthday!</h1>
  <canvas id="birthday">
            </canvas>
</section>
</main>

<!--===== SCROLL REVEAL =====-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>

<!--===== MAIN JS =====-->
<!-- script src="assets/js/main.js"></script -->
```

Answer (score -4):

You can wrap it in a div and then use text-align center.

Comment: Not Working Brother

Comment: This will not center anything vertically. Also, you should copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution. Please see [answer] and take the [tour].